# Why is typescript-transformer and custom rn-cli config needed for react-native ts?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am following react native blog post about working with typescript: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native

One thing I can't grasp is why we need https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer alongside custom rn-cli config?

To my understanding we can transpile ts to a folder like `dist` and include main `App` from there in our root level `index.js` file.

For this to work a simple script that launches typescript compiler alongside react native one will do the trick or am I missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Native uses a module bundler called [Metro](https://facebook.github.io/metro/), and the `react-native-typescript-transformer` plugin allows it to build your project's TypeScript files as part of the bundling process much like how you can use the [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) plugin to transform TypeScript files as a part of its bundling process.

With both Metro and Webpack you pre-build your TypeScript files with `tsc` instead of using a bundler plugin if that's what you'd prefer - this is just an alternative to doing that.

Comment: I see, at this point do we need to keep `.babelrc` preset in, as typescript supports jsx?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it still uses Babel for dealing with the source files in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/*` - those JS files are all still in their un-transformed Flow + JSX form.

Comment: `react-native-typescript-transformer` didn't do much for me, so I wnet ahead with simple `tsc --watch` before normal metro bundler flow. Removed .babelrc and everything seems to be working fine so far, project relies on a lot of react-native modules. I checked the files and indeed they are not transpiled, so am a bit confused.